# How to implement Pentago AI algorithm

Tags: c#, minimax

i'm trying to develop `Pentago`-game in c#.

right now i'm having 2 players mode which working just fine.

the problem is, that i want *One player* mode (against computer), but unfortunately, all implements of minimax / negamax are for **one** thing calculated for each "Move" (placing marble, moving game-piece).

butin `Pentago`, every player need to do **two** things (place marble, and rotate one of the inner-boards)

I didn't figure out how to implement both rotate part & placing the marble, and i would love someone to guide me with this.

if you're not familiar with the game, here's a [link](http://www.pentago-online.com) to the game.

if anyone want's, i can upload my code somewhere if that's relevant.

**thank you very much in advance**

Comment: What have you done so far? any specific issues you are having?

Comment: as for what have i done so far - i tried to start implementing minimax, but i didnt understand how to "represent" **one** move (while it's suppose to be **two**) and save a `List<Moves>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a single legal moves consists of two sub-moves, then your "move" for game algorithm purposes is simply a tuple where the first item is the marble placement and the second item is the board rotation e.g.:

```
var marbleMove = new MarbleMove(fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol);
var boardRotation = new BoardRotation(subBoard, rotationDirection);
var move = new Tuple<MarblMove, BoardRotation>(marbleMove, boardRotation);
```

Typically a game playing algorithm will require you to enumerate all possible moves for a given position.  In this case, you must enumerate **all possible pairs** of sub-moves.  With this list in hand you can move on to using standing computer game playing approaches.

Comment: i guess you ment to 
    `var marblePlace = new MarblePlace(onRow,onCol)`


anyway, is that mean i need to instance all possabile pairs ? isn't that gonna be VERY slow ?

Comment: Yes, it could be slow and game algorithms often have to cope with the exponential explosion of game positions.  Your first friend to help with this problem is the transposition table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_table

Answer (score 1):

Rick suggested tuples above, but you might want to actually just have each player make two independent moves, so it remains their turn twice in a row. This can make move ordering easier, but may complicate your search algorithm, depending on which one you are using.

In an algorithm like UCT (which is likely to outperform minimax for simple implementations) breaking into two moves can be more efficient because the algorithm can first figure out what moves placements are good, and then figure out what rotation is best. (Googling UCT doesn't give much. The original research paper isn't very insightful, but this page might be better: http://senseis.xmp.net/?UCT)

Comment: UCT looks like "Monte-Carlo" to me. if not, i didnt got it. can you provide a short example of the UCT algorithm?

Comment: Monte-Carlo can mean a lot of things; UCT is in the broader class of Monte-Carlo Tree Searching (MCTS) algorithms. UCT has an exploration rule, that tell you where to sample next. Usually the UCT tree grows in the areas that are being sampled, and random or pseudo-random samples are performed to get from the end of the UCT tree to the end of the game. This avoids the need for a complicated evaluation function.