# How to implement c# tree using List<T> (for Pentago AI )

Tags: c#, list, tree

I'm trying to implement Pentago AI and found the code snippet below in the : "http://snipd.net/minimax-algorithm-with-alpha-beta-pruning-in-c" about alpha beta pruning 
and evaluation function . As you see in code snippet a subtree can be created using " List " .
but unfortunately I don`t have enough information because  I'm a beginner . please help me you , experts and professionals...
thank you .

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
    }

    public List<Node> Children(bool Player)
    {
        List<Node> children = new List<Node>();

        // Create your subtree here and return the results *****==>*** here is my problem ********

        return children;
    }

    public bool IsTerminal(bool Player)
    {
        terminalNode = false;

        // Game over?

        return terminalNode;
    }

    public int GetTotalScore(bool Player)
    {
        int totalScore = 0;

         //evaluation function
               return totalScore;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the way the tree works is that each node is a `Node` class and that class has a `List<Node>` of the child nodes to that node. Which will define your tree. Is that what you're not understanding, or are you unable to build that tree, or something else?

Comment: thanks for your answer , I don't know how to make "my own subtree".

Comment: if you're not familiar with the game, here's a [link] (www.pentago-online.com) to the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't actually write your code, but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is everything you need to know about lists in C#. also, this is a code snippet. what you need is an AI algorithm for playing this game. I couldn't find one for free...
You can also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564936/how-to-implement-pentago-ai-algorithm) on another guy who had a similar problem.
finally if you wish to create the algorithm, start by figure out that points would you give to each spot and in what conditions, and at each step calculate these points

Comment: thank you so much, but I have problem with these part I`ve mentioned not with the list itself .

Comment: for any question about implementing pentago AI you can count on me ! just let me know through this email : mantera.sh@hotmail.com . I would answer in this wonderful Q & A website...

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/

It explains how to make tree structured data in c#.

Comment: Hey Leonardo, welcome to StackOverflow. Although your the post you refer to probably describes a relevant solution, it is what is known on this site as a link-only answer. StackOverflow wants the minimum information to be available on the site itself for various reasons. Unless you add more information, your answer will likely be closed.